# Zoho Subscriptions Webhooks Validate

Tags: php

I want to use zoho subscriptions to make recurring payments on my website.
I use webhooks to send data for creating membership.
Now I want to validate the data from webhook to check if the webhook was really sent.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: How to check if the webhook was really sent and the payment was received?

Comment: The API server will return a status code indicating success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

You should read webhooks data and validate by Zoho signature after that, check the **event_type** which indicates the event, it could be **subscription_cancelled**, **subscription_cancellation_scheduled**, **new_subscription**. Also, you should get a subscription id, customer id inside of data->subscription->. Below a sample webhooks body

```
{
  "created_time":"...",
  "event_id":"...",
  "event_type":"...",
  "event_source":"...",
  "event_time":"...",
  "data": {
    "subscription": {
      "subscription_id": "...",
      "created_time": "...",
      "customer_id":"...",
      "...": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you have a subscription id, customer id, you can call Zoho subscription info API to get subscription details for cross-checking. Another way, you have event_id so, now, you can retrieve event details to validate that webhooks really comes from Zoho.